# to have a lot of guts

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, expressions, idiom-request

Are there any other expressions to say "I have a lot of guts"? 
The situation is you want to express that you have enough courage and conviction in a job interview.

Comment: heaven-daring ........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that you have ***courage*** if you just mean bravery, or ***gumption*** if you mean initiative and resourcefulness, and the sort of courage you need to challenge authority and the status quo. You could use ***wherewithal***; some dictionaries suggest that this is only related to having enough money for something, but certainly modern usage in my experience is broader - it means whatever is needed for something, but that could be money, resources, time, ability, or whatever. Essentially, it's a fancy way of saying "I've got what it takes". If you want to be a bit more fluffy about it, you could say that you have ***heart***, but it's very much in the eye of the beholder what *that* means.

If you're using any of these - *guts*, *courage*, *gumption* etc. - you don't want to just say that you have a lot of them/it. It comes across as weird and unclear. You want to say that you have what it takes to do *something*. *Wherewithal* is particularly only meaningful when used in relation to a particular purpose:

> I've got the wherewithal to see this through.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *guts*, but I'd advise against saying "I have a lot of guts." The problem is, it's too easy to get your audience distracted by the obvious joke, which is predicated on the fact that *a lot of guts* *can* be construed to mean "a large belly."

A better way to use *guts* would be to say something like:

> I have the guts to see this job through to success.

or

> I understand the kind of guts it takes to do this job right.